# Como se puede implementar una tabla dinamica en sweetalert2 y que se ejecute desde el componente

Tags: angular7, sweetalert2

Lo que tengo es esto:

```
return Swal.fire({
    html:`<div id="page">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Codigo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">A :</th>
                    <td>Descripcion del codigo a </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">B :</th>
                    <td>Descripcion del codigo b</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>`,
    focusConfirm: false,
    allowOutsideClick: false
});
```

Pero quiero recorrerlo dentro del html de `Swal.fire` utilizando este objeto:

```
mensajeDinamico: [
    {
        "codigo": "A",
        "mensaje": "Descripcion del codigo a"
    },
    {
        "codigo": "B",
        "mensaje": "Descripcion del codigo b"
    }
]
```

Y salga asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No conozco angular, pero con javascript, podrías definir una variable fuera del swal con todas las etiqutas hasta <tbody>, luego iterar sobre el array e ir concatenando en la variable las etiquetas <tr> con el contenido de cada elemento del array, y finalmente concatenar las etiquetas de cierre. Y al método html de swal le pasa esa variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias si señor lo que hice fue crear un metodo que me retorne todo el html e iterando el objeto asi funciono gracias.

Comment: Genial! Ten en cuenta que tu solución puede también servirle a otros con la misma pregunta, así que te comento que [Puedes responder a tu propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), así la solución queda registrada en el sitio para toda la comunidad. Puedes leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para tener una idea de cómo hacerlo. Saludos.